# Laravel shows unrendered Blade template when view file is updated

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Every time I make even the smallest change to any of my views, the corresponding page shows an unrendered blade template in the browser (including all `"{{ .. }}"` and `@` directives). However, this happens only once. If I refresh the same page - the blade is rendered and displayed properly until I make another change in the view file and then the whole cycle repeats.

Anyone had this issue?

Here is an overview of my environment and what I already tried:

- Laravel is running locally in `Homestead/Vagrant` (tried to restart Vagrant)
- Laravel is using the local environment (`APP_ENV=local, APP_DEBUG=true, CACHE_DRIVER=file`)
- Tried `php artisan cache:clear` - the template is rendered properly after this command until I make a change to any view

Comment: Does [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-not-rendering) help you?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI, doesn't look like permissions is the issue. Resources and Storage folders both have 0755

Comment: Your blade page extension is `.blade.php`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the correct naming and in general everything works fine. Feels like the issue is in how Laravel handles the cache file. If cache is no longer relevant, Laravel would dump raw/unrendered template into the browser and update the cache, after which page refresh shows properly rendered template

Comment: Never had this problem, what web server are you using ? It sounds like a cache problem 

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36161

Comment: @Eloise85, the server is running inside a virtual machine (See [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead) - this is based on Ubuntu)

Comment: @sta, A member of my team posted that..

Comment: OK, I'm not facing this becaus I use laragon for local dev and a classic LAMP VPS for stagging.